# How to get vertical spacing between floated elements?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, css-float, user-experience

Here is the UI prototype I am trying to implement[image]

Here is my current layout and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5r1ojjdn/2)[image]

The way I went about designing the look of this was having the campaign and timestamp floated to the right so that the rest of the text would wrap around it rather than intersect. If anyone else has any suggestions, I am all ears.

My question is regarding the red section I highlighted. I am trying get some spacing between the campaign and the timestamp in my case. 
These are the styles I've tried applying on the timestamp

```
#time_stamp {
    color: #B67F30;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    transform: translateY(20px);
}
```

I know that the style itself is working because margin-left and color are taking effect. However both attributes that I used to give vertical spacing, margin-top and transform:translateY are not having any effects. Does anyone know what the issue is? Should I use different styles or a different design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try divs instead of spans

```
<div id="updates"> 
    <h1 id="vertical"><img src="mark.png" />Recent Updates</h1>
    <div id="tofloat"> 
        <div id="headline">Campaign </div> <BR />  
        <div id="time_stamp">2014.02.14</div>
    </div>
    <p>
         Loreum ipsum doloar sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit. Etiam in sagittis nisl. Donec et convallis eros, quis volutpat.
    </p>            
</div>
```

JFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5r1ojjdn/7/

Comment: Is there a better way to do this - style wise - rather than having a div inside a div inside another div?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because `<span>` is an **inline** element. And inline elements are not affected by the `margin` property. So, you could make your "Convert" button to behave like a block element, and still stay inline, by doing this:

```
#headline {
    ...
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;  /* now it will work */
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5r1ojjdn/8/)

Comment: ahh i see. That's why margin top wasn't working. You know why transform: translate wasn't working though?  Nothing here - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp  says that this style must be applied to a block element.